# Receiver cannot resolved to a variable Android error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm a beginner in Android. I'm trying to register and unregister the receiver dynamically. But I'm getting an error in code. I tried to register and unregister the receiver like this:

**Register**:

```
this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"));
```

**unregister:**

```
this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        Toast.makeText(this, "UnRegistered broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

But in both the statements it's giving the same error:

> receiver cannot resolved to a variable

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: where is receiver initialized?

Comment: Can you update the error stack trace please

Comment: okay..I got it..I need to create the instance of my Broadcastreciever and i should pass that instance in the register and unregister method..I'm I right?

Comment: @user3619298 yes you should

Answer (score 0):

Define and initialize your receiver before registering it.

you can **define** it out of your `onCreat` :

```
/**
     * the BroadcastReceiver definition
     */
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
```

than initialize it for exemple in your `onCreat` (before registration) :

```
// the BroadcastReceiver initialization
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// do something when your receiver is called
}
};
```

Then you can register it and unregister it ...